# Changing x-label values to x- label names

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I have the following data set, which I want to plot in a graph. These are the results of a single experiment (my apologies for some dutch names).

```
structure(list(exp = c("JU-05", "JU-05", "JU-05", "JU-05", "JU-05", 
"JU-05", "JU-05", "JU-05", "JU-05", "JU-05", "JU-05", "JU-05"
), samples = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), donor = c("22-199", 
"22-199", "22-199", "22-199", "22-199", "22-199", "22-199", "22-199", 
"22-199", "22-199", "22-199", "22-199"), bacterie = c(NA, NA, 
"LUH14616", "LUH14616", "LUH14616", "LUH14616", "LUH14616", "LUH14616", 
"LUH14616", "LUH14616", "LUH14616", "LUH14616"), treat = c(1, 
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6), treatment = c("control", "control", 
"no filter", "no filter", "200 um", "200 um", "100 um", "100 um", 
"70 um", "70 um", "5' 1000 rpm", "5' 1000 rpm"), cfu.x = c(0, 
0, 3, 26, 0, 0, 23, 6, 68, 21, 46, 18), verdunning.x = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 0), cfu_ml_1 = c(0, 0, 150, 1300, 
0, 0, 1.15e+08, 3e+05, 3.4e+07, 10500000, 2300000, 900), x200_ul = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), cfu_ml_2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), cfu_ml = c(0, 0, 150, 1300, 
0, 0, 1.15e+08, 3e+05, 3.4e+07, 10500000, 2300000, 900), gewenst_cfu = c(1e+05, 
1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 
1e+05, 1e+05), cfu.y = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), 
    verdunning.y = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), werkelijk = c(2.5e+07, 
    2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 
    2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 2.5e+07, 2.5e+07), ul_opgebracht = c(5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), inoculum_bwm = c(125000, 
    125000, 125000, 125000, 125000, 125000, 125000, 125000, 125000, 
    125000, 125000, 125000)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

[image: This is the graph I got this far]

I want to change the column values (now 1-6) to the names of the treatment. I already found functions that manually assign the label names, but I want R to extract these names from my treatment column. The code I used to build the plot is

```
ggplot(
  data = ju_05_data,
  mapping = aes(x = treat, y = cfu_ml)) +
  geom_point()+
   stat_summary(
    fun = "mean",
    geom = "point",
    col = "red")+
scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
              labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+
  labs(
    title = "JU-05",
    y = "CFU/ml",
    x = "treatment")

ggsave("ju_05_data.png")
```

[image: This is the graph I got this far]

Which gives me a plot with the x-values in numbers, but I want the treatment names. How do I extract these names from the treatment column?

I tried to add the scale_x_continuous(labels() or scale_x_discrete(labels() code, but this does not do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As `treatment` is a column of your dataframe you could achieve your desired result by mapping `treatment` on `x`. To get the right order I added an `reorder` to convert to a `factor` and to order the levels according to `treat`:

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

ju_05_data$treatment <- reorder(ju_05_data$treatment, ju_05_data$treat)

ggplot(
  data = ju_05_data,
  mapping = aes(x = treatment, y = cfu_ml)) +
  geom_point()+
  stat_summary(
    fun = "mean",
    geom = "point",
    col = "red")+
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+
  labs(
    title = "JU-05",
    y = "CFU/ml",
    x = "treatment")
```

[image]